# Scrapy Error: Can't Find Callback

Tags: scrapy

Scrapy 1.0, Python 2.7.9, Ubuntu 15.04.

I've seen a lot of similar issues on SO, but they are all slightly different and none of them mention the *can't find callback* error.

My problem is that I can't get any output from my **CrawlSpider**. I have successfully used the BaseSpider (now scrapy.Spider) both in the DMOZ example and on my target site.

I can successfully pull things down from the command line. But for some reason, my CrawlSpider gets nothing at all.

The code example here is just one of many iterations. I have tried with a CrawlSpider and with a scrapy.Spider.

I have tried to both yield and return a Request and an Item. I have put my callback on the Rule, and on the Method. Nothing has worked.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, and it is probably small, easy, and obvious, but I'm not getting it.

```
import re
import scrapy

from test2.items import Test2Item

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't350_crawl2'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com/350/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('350/'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('350.+?\.html'), deny=('public.', 'labs\.creativecommons\.org')), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        default_output_processor = Join()
        item = Test2Item()
        item['shortTitle'] = response.xpath("//p[@class = 'parties']/text()").extract()
        item['offCite'] = response.xpath("//p[@class = 'case_cite']/text()").extract()
        item['arrow'] = response.xpath("//p[@class = 'parties']/text()").extract()
        item['arrow'] = response.xpath("//p[@class = 'case_cite']/text()").extract()
        item['bodyText'] = response.xpath("//*/p").extract()
        return item

    def print_items(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Please check you indentation. The StackOverflow editor allows you to paste some code, and then, use the `{}` button to ident it correctly (after selecting it). You need to define `parse_item` inside the spider class (1 level indentation more than `class MySpider()`)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone out there who reaches this thread, I will suggest to **change all your tab indentations to spaces**. I spent some good hours to figure this out. Even if the callback method is within the class, I was struggling with AttributeError. This happened to me while using sublime text.

Hope this helps someone.